# What does R^d in last lines refer to

Tags: vector-spaces, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

[image: http://sarielhp.org/papers/04/survey/survey.pdf]

The image above is snapshot in the journal Geometric Approximation `http://sarielhp.org/papers/04/survey/survey.pdf` via Coresets .I could not figure out what is the R^d refers in it.

Comment: It should be the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space?

Comment: Yeah it is !! thanks @John

Answer (score 1):

It is the d-dimensional (real) [euclidean hyper-plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) $\mathbb{R}^d$

Comment: Furthermore I would not call $\mathbb{R}^d$ a hyper-plane since hyper-planes are defined relatively to a higher dimensional space which is not the case here.

Comment: @WillemHagemann, yes ok, i used the word "hyper-plane" in the sense of higher-dimensional plane, assuming $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the euclidean plane (in the context of geometry to be precise but by an abuse of language or analogy one can say for related fields as well)

Comment: I had to remove my first comment, where I claimed that $\mathbb{R}^d$ has a richer sructure than the Euclidean Space. I was misled by the notion of a Euclidean field (any positive element has a square root). In contrast, a Euclidean space is complete (which is stronger than the demand that any positive number has a square root). Hence $\mathbb{R}^d$ is indeed a Euclidean Space. I apologize for any confusion.